# Laravel 5.7 making Auth

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have some issue about Laravel Auth. I already make my own page with Laravel and now I want to add user login. So I used `php artisan make:auth` and it went smoothly but. My auth doesn't show up on my index page. I think, it's because I already change Laravel's main page. And now, how can I display it on my own main page.

So Laravel Auth came with the Home Controller and with Route in web file. I already changed it to my main page which is welcome.blade but still can not see login and register bar at right top?

*Controller*

```
public function index()
    {
        return view('welcome');
    }
```

*Route*

```
Route::get('welcome', 'HomeController@index')->name('welcome');
```

How can I call it Auth's register and login link to my main mage(welcome.blade)?

*welcome.blade*

```
<div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
          @if (Route::has('login'))
              <div class="top-right links">
                  @auth
                      <a href="{{ url('welcome') }}">Home</a>
                  @else
                      <a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>

                      @if (Route::has('register'))
                          <a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a>
                      @endif
                  @endauth
              </div>
          @endif
      </div>
```

I am calling on page with the code above. But doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this:

```
Route::group( ['middleware' => 'auth' ], function()
{
     Route::get('welcome', 'HomeController@index')->name('welcome');
});



Route::get('login', 'LoginController@showLogin')->name('login');
Route::get('register', 'RegisterController@register')->name('register');
```

Comment: but what about the main.page call?  Controller and Route is okay with this but. How can I call register and login on main page? I already using Laravel's default auth but it doesn't display

Comment: @Potti: Please put your login & register route

Comment: okay thanks I have got the Auth, but my register isn't working. what is the I think that's because I deleted the users migration from database. How can I create a new users migration?

Comment: @Potti: Please delete your users migration name from  migrations table and run `php artisan migrate`

Comment: there is nothing in the migration table. so if I use php artisan migrate, there is nothing to migrate. How can I create a users migration for a database? I am asking this.

Comment: @Potti: Please check your users migration file in migration folder?

Comment: sir this is the problem I delete those migration files  a long time ago. So i have nothing to migrate now. I am asking how can I create a new migration. what user needs in the table?

Comment: @Potti: pLease run `php  artisan make:auth` command and check then run `php artisan migrate` command

Comment: sir, I already done that. migration files not coming with that commad. I need those table. where can I find default tables?

Comment: @Potti: Thanks for accepting my answer and please upvote to my answer if my solution work for you

Answer (score 0):

If you want it only single routes. Just chain middleware('auth') at the end of your route. 
Example:

```
Route::get('welcome', 'HomeController@index')->name('welcome')->middleware('auth');
```

You can customize it.

You can group your routes with this middleware as suggested by saurabh dhariwal

**On your edit.**
Make a route. And on that route controller return the view of your register page and login page. Simple as that